# Difference between using async APIs vs. wrapping sync APIs in CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading, http, asynchronous, io

I was looking through the [Apache Http Client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/index.html) docs and noticed they offer both a sync and an async API. The same goes for [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/).

What is the difference between using the async APIs these libraries provide versus using the sync APIs and just wrapping calls with CompletableFutures and using dedicated thread pools?

Any resources that can help me understand this topic better are also welcomed.

Comment: I fail to see how you’re comment is helpful @Holger

Comment: You are asking about the difference between using the library’s implementation and your own implementation of basically the same thing. The only relevant difference is that in one case, you have more work in implementing what the library has already done. If you have a more specific problem, ask a more specific question.